# Adding one extra condition makes a 262ms query into a 28s query, why?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is my query

```
SELECT

DATE(ar.created_at) AS my_date,

COUNT(*) AS requests,
SUM(ar.is_scrubbed) AS scrubbed_requests,
SUM(ar.has_state_mismatch) AS state_mismatch_total,
AVG(ar.special_result) AS special_avg

FROM advert_requests ar
LEFT JOIN placements p ON p.id = ar.placement_id

WHERE ar.created_at >= '2022-11-22' AND ar.created_at < '2022-11-25'

-- why adding this takes so much longer?
AND p.site_id = 3

AND ar.debug = 0

GROUP BY my_date
ORDER BY my_date DESC;
```

WITHOUT the `AND p.site_id = 3` it takes around 200-300ms

EXPLAIN

[image]

WITH the `AND p.site_id = 3` it can take anywhere between 4 and 28 seconds.

EXPLAIN

[image]

Anyone any idea why (cc/ @bill-karwin)

Comment: The basic answer is that the optimizer has to choose between a different set of plans  to accoung for the additional `AND p.site_id = 3` condition. This includes consideration of `placements_site_id_index`, usage of which the optimizer ultimately concludes is the approach that would be the most efficient. Your screenshot (please use text in the future) of the first explain plan has the `rows` value truncated. Updating stats could help, but its difficult to give any concrete advice without further information.